# Facebook Graph API Permissions Invalid Scopes

Tags: flutter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-permissions

I am building a mobile app using Flutter and flutter_facebook_login package. I request the following permissions during login:

- pages_show_list
- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_insights
- pages_read_engagement
- user_birthday
- user_gender
- user_location

I have always obtained these permissions without any issue up until now. This is the error I get upon login:

**Invalid Scopes: user_birthday, user_gender, user_location. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions**

My app is currently in test mode. I have never encountered this error before it only recently started appearing. It only appears when I attempt to login using my admin account not using a test user account. It still prevents me from login it into my app.

I have read on another question that the app requires review to request those permissions, but is that a new requirement even in test mode? I thought we could test these permissions before requesting review for live mode.

Comment: Are you sure you actually spelled them correctly? According to the error message, you have used a dot instead of underscore.

Comment: I made a mistake when copying the message. I edited the question.

Comment: Looks like they limited the availability of specific sets of permissions to certain app types now, more details below your other question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66167380/1427878