# Facebook Graph API Mutually Exclusive Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-permissions

For our app, we need the following permissions:

- instagram_manage_insights, which falls under the Business App Type
- user_birthday, which falls under the Consumer App Type

Is there any way for us to obtain both permissions or they are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like certain sets of features and permissions are mutually exclusive now, since they are available in different app types only.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types says,

> Once you choose an app type, your app will only be presented with products, permissions, and features that are available to that app type.

So anything that is not on the list for a specific type, won’t be available for you to choose from to add to your app.

`instagram_manage_insights` is only listed under Business, and `user_birthday` only under consumer. So if you really need both, then you will have to create two separate apps, and then correlate the data somehow on your end* – if that is still allowed.

---

* The [Customer Matching API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/customer-matching) would have allowed to match app-scoped user ids across different apps that belong to a business entity, but that appears to be deprecated now.